# Sort by alphabetical permutation

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, alphabetical-sort

I am trying to implement a sorting algorithm that sorts a list of words by a given alphabetical permutation. (For example, if given the permutation "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba" and a list of words "ant, bear, cat, zoo, animal" my algorithm would return "zoo, cat, bear, ant, animal") I can think of a way to do this by comparing each letter of the words with letters from another word but this would take way too long. is there an optimized way of implementing this algorithm so it can sort the words quicker?

Comment: Try something first.......

Comment: as far as i know you can use hashmap to save previous processes in order to avoid calculate previous processes again

Comment: check how `String.compareTo()` implemeted and just replace char codes with your custom weights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom comparator using a HashMap:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static class PermutationComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        private final Map<Character, Integer> order;

        public PermutationComparator(String permutation) {
            this.order = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < permutation.length(); i++) {
                order.put(permutation.charAt(i), i);
            }
        }

        private int getOrder(char c) {
            Integer value = order.get(c);
            if (value == null) return -1;
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(o1.length(), o2.length()); i++) {
                int compare = Integer.compare(getOrder(o1.charAt(i)), getOrder(o2.charAt(i)));
                if (compare != 0) return compare;
            }
            return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] strings = {"ant", "bear", "cat", "zoo", "animal"};
        Arrays.sort(strings, new PermutationComparator("zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
    }
}
```

Please notice this comparator puts everything other than the chars you defined before anything else. If you want to put them after anything else, use:

```
if (value == null) return order.size();
```

If you want to be case insensitive, use:

```
Integer value = order.get(Character.toLowerCase(c));
```